# Can't enable network from system indicator

Tags: settings, system, networking, release-odin

When connected to a wireless network, clicking on the network system indicator shows two buttons (with the wireless button displaying as enabled) at the top of the context menu. I can click on the wireless network to disable it. The wireless button displays as disabled and the list of access points disappears as expected.

However, if I now try to enable wireless by clicking on the button again, I can't. It has no effect. It seems the button, as well as the service, is disabled. To re-enable wireless I have to go into the System Settings. Is this normal? (a bug?) or is there a problem with my installation which needs to be corrected?

Comment: This is a known bug that's been there for some years already. https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network/issues/16

Comment: Thank you. I should have searched for "wifi" as well as "network". It's an annoyance rather than a problem so I suppose the fix is a long way down the priority list. As it's on the list, I'm marking this as solved.

Comment: I forgot it needs an answer to be marked as solved. @Maccer. If you could put your comment in an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known and confirmed bug](http://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network/issues/16), my question has been fully answered.